# CocoonJS draws shadow around tiles

Tags: html5, html-canvas

I am using CocoonJS launcher on iOS for a simple tiled game. Calling canvas drawImage for tiles adds a shadow or ghost border around tiles. See this screenshot:
http://martindrapeau.github.io/cocoon-mario/img/screenshot.png

The canvas is 960 pixels wide. Using viewport meta tag:

Using CocoonJS Launcher 2.1.1.2 on iOS 8 (iPad mini and iPhone 6).
Same behavior with anti-aliasing turned off.
Same behavior with Scale Aspect Fit and No Scale.

If someone could help me eliminate this problem, would be great.

Extra notes:
See here for the zip to try it out in the CocoonJS launcher:
http://martindrapeau.github.io/cocoon-mario/cocoon-mario.zip

And the HTML5 game to play in your browser. Notice it looks find in any browser.
http://martindrapeau.github.io/cocoon-mario/